# How can I add a global control to check user has updated her/his profile?

Tags: web-part, user-profile, feature

Is there any control/feature/webpart I can add to trigger a functionality globally in any page on a Sharepoint?

I now have a webpart on the homepage that checks if a user is due to update her/his profile and shows a popup asking to confirm the details or edit them if they have changed.

**The problem is** that if user has bookmarks or changes the url location and never goes through the home page it won't trigger that functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a delegate control and add it in the MasterPage. That way it will trigger on any page inheriting the masterpage.

Comment: That sounds/looks what I need for this task, thanks.